# Ping command results in packet loss

Tags: networking, centos, ping

Whenever I `ping` on my personal computer, nothing gets displayed other than a single statement.

Upon stopping execution, I see that several packets were transmitted in the statistics. On top of all this, I'm getting a rather absurd packet loss.

What can I do to make `ping` react in a sane manner?

I am running **Centos 6.5 64bit**.

Below is an example output when I try `ping google.com`:

```
[root@Virus os]# ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.230.160) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4274ms
```

`ifconfig -a`:

```
[root@Virus os]# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:29:FE:D7  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9081 (8.8 KiB)  TX bytes:9081 (8.8 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:4B:F5:14:9B:58  
          inet addr:172.20.40.55  Bcast:172.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::864b:f5ff:fe14:9b58/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:55308863 (52.7 MiB)  TX bytes:6291284 (5.9 MiB)
```

`iptables -L`:

```
[root@Virus www]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`netstat -nr`:

```
[root@Virus www]# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         172.20.4.254    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
```

Comment: That's standard behaviour when you don't get any ping responses. Does `ping localhost` produce the same output?

Comment: ping localhost works fine. I didnt know it was standard. Is there something I can do to get responses?

Comment: Check your network connection, check if you can ping an ip address instead. e.g `ping 8.8.8.8` one of googles public dns servers. Also post  `ifconfig -a`

Comment: I cant ping an ip either and I have just updated the question with the ifconfig -a

Comment: It seems you have DNS problems.  Look at `/etc/resolv.conf` and update the file accordingly by adding your ISP dns server or  simply  `nameserver 8.8.8.8` . Try to ping google again.

Comment: Still doesnt work. Ive added nameserver 8.8.8.8 but Im still getting no results.

Comment: Is iptables configured?  Check the output of `iptables -L`. @val0x00ff Why do you think there's a DNS issue?  The domain (`google.com`) is correctly resolved (`74.125.230.160`).

Comment: It has nothing to do with DNS. `PING google.com (74.125.230.160)` is resolving the name. Do a netstat -nr and post the response here. Most probably you have a routing problem. First of all I would disconnect the router from the internet. Then I would disable iptables, then I would try pinging the router, if router is reached obviously I have a routing problem which is what I thought in first place, otherwise connection from PC to router should be checked.

Comment: Im on a wireless network. Could that be the problem. I dont have router access.

Comment: If you're on a wireless network you have a router (you are conected to one) unless you are connected ad hoc, in which case you are connected to another computer or device without intermediaries in that case that computer/device must act as a router for you to be able to connect to the internet. But that is a special case and I doubt you are on that one.

Comment: By the way, your gateway seems to be 172.20.4.254, try to ping it. If it responds, then try to traceroute google.com and see where you are stoping receiving pings (traceroute is a ping tool with times). If you reach the router but you can't get past it, then check the router there must be a rule there not letting you pass through it.

Comment: you dont have ip address asigned for your eth0, how you asigned ip address static or via dhcp ?

Comment: Use traceroute command to find out at which node traffic is getting stopped. Looks like you are connected to LAN but not connected to internet. Do you use proxy to access internet websites? If yes then you are not directly connected to internet but connected to internet through proxy and ping to internet IPs will not work